# A Problem on circular permutation.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

We need to find the number of arrangements of 6 people at three identical round tables if each table must be occupied.

I tried to break it down into cases, like (1,1,4) , (1,2,3) , (2,2,2) as they are identical, the order won't matter in terms of number of people on a table. Also i am aware of the fact that number of ways of arranging $n$ people in a circle is $(n-1)!$. Also, i know if we need to arrange x objects in a line, where $ x_1 $ are of one kind, $x_2 $are of another kind and so , number of ways would be $= \frac{x!}{x_1!x_2!...x_k!}$ but i am not sure how to string these facts together for this problem.

Like for example of case (1,2,3) , first $\binom{6}{3}$ to select three people for first table , then $\binom{3}{2}$ to select two people for second table which automatically selects 1 person for first table. Then $\frac{\binom{6}{3} \cdot \binom{3}{2} \cdot 2}{z}$ but i am not able to figure out what that $z$ is going to be.

I would appreciate it if along with the answer you could also tell me method to handle these problems.

Comment: I assume you meant to say that the number of ways of arranging $n$ people in a circle is $(n - 1)!$.

Comment: Are the tables to be treated as distinct, that is *labelled* ?

Comment: @trueblueanil no, they are exactly identical

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes sorry, i have fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking first at the case $(1,2,3)$, you could call the table with $3$ people $A$, the table with $2$ people $B$, and the table with $1$ person $C$. The number of assignments of people to tables equals the number of arrangements of the word $AAABBC$ and is $\frac{6!}{3!\,2!\,1!}$ or $\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1}$. I see both sorts of expressions in your attempted solution, except that your expression involving binomial coefficients has a factor $\frac{2}{z}$ that I don't understand.

At any rate, the next step is to arrange the people at each table, which, as you mention can be done in $2!\,1!\,0!$ ways. So the result is
$$
\frac{6!}{3!\,2!\,1!}\cdot2!\,1!\,0!=\frac{6!}{3\cdot2\cdot1}.
$$

For a case like $(1,1,4)$ you have to account for the interchangeability of the two tables with $1$ person, so you get
$$
\frac{6!}{2!\cdot4!\,1!\,1!}\cdot3!\,0!\,0!=\frac{6!}{2!\cdot4\cdot1\cdot1}.
$$

You can do the third case by the same principle. You should know that there is a systematic analysis of this problem: your problem is equivalent to finding the number of permutations of $6$ objects that have $3$ cycles in their cycle decomposition. This is the [Stirling number of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) $\left[6 \atop 3\right]$.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of requiring students to infer the implications of the words "circular" and "identical" in problems like this. But the meaning, I presume, is that two arrangements are considered identical when every person has the same left and right neighbors in two arrangements, irrespective of which physical chairs people are seated in or which physical tables they are seated at. So with this interpretation, we label the 4-person table $A$, one of the $1$-person tables $B$, and the other $1$-person table $C$. Since swapping tables $B$ and $C$ produces an equivalent arrangement, words...

Comment: ...$ACAABA$ and $ABAACA$ are considered the same. Likewise, in the $(2,2,2)$ case, the word $ABBCAC$ is considered the same as $ACCBAB$ or $BAACBC$ or $BCCABA$ or $CAABCB$ or $CBBACA$. The multinomial coefficient $\frac{x!}{x_1!\,x_2!\,\ldots\,x_k!}$ must therefore be divided by appropriate factorials to account for these letter interchanges.